# Printing an ArrayList multiple times

Tags: java

I'm working on the guessing method inside my hangman game. It takes a letter that the user wants to guess and checks it with each letter in the word.

```
public void checkGuess(String guessLetter)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < gameWord.length(); i++)
    {
        if(guessLetter.charAt(0) == (gameWord.charAt(i)))
        {
            hideword[i] = guessLetter.charAt(0);

        }
        else
        {
            hideword[i] = '_';
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hideword);
}
```

That current code gets me an input of:

```
Have another user enter a word to play with:

Apple 
 Welcome to hang man! Below is your word:

 _ _ _ _ _ Enter a letter to guess
 p

 _pp__

 Enter a letter to guess

  l

  ___l_

 Enter a letter to guess
```

Is there anyway to make it so it would print the "p" and the "l" together, instead of separate lines like it is?

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
else
{
    hideword[i] = '_';
}
```

From your loop. Otherwise, the previous progress is being overwritten. `hideword` should be filled with `'_'` when the game starts, and then modified as the game progresses.

Something like this, using [`Arrays.fill(char[], char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(char[],%20char)):

```
public Game(String word) {
    gameWord = word;
    hideword = new char[word.length()];
    Arrays.fill(hideword, '_'); // import java.util.Arrays;
}

public void checkGuess(String guessLetter) {
    for(int i = 0; i < gameWord.length(); i++)
        if(guessLetter.charAt(0) == (gameWord.charAt(i)))
            hideword[i] = guessLetter.charAt(0);
    System.out.println(hideword);
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to use `Arrays.fill()` when initializing `hideword`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this by just **initialing the hideword by array of _**(where length of array is the total no of characters in gameWord) and removing else part from your code

```
public void checkGuess(String guessLetter) {
    for(int i = 0; i < gameWord.length(); i++) {
        if(guessLetter.charAt(0) == (gameWord.charAt(i))) {
            hideword[i] = guessLetter.charAt(0);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hideword);
}
```

What is happening in your code that your every match is overriding the result of your first last match in the else part of your code, so if you would remove that it will work fine because we have already initialized the hideword by _ _ _ _

Comment: How would I initialize it like that? Since its a Char array I can't really add in "_"

Comment: 4castle has mentioned the way. Thanks 4castle.